# Certificate not valid for jfrog.io when using Docker registry

Tags: docker, artifactory

The documentation says I have to use jfrog.io and not jfrog.com. I also tried to login into jfrog.com, which did not work.

So it looks like acme.jfrog.io/acme is the right way to access my Docker registry.

Note: Also the hostname was missing in the description. I was only able to upload when specifying the full name, and setting the registry as insecure in my Docker configuration.

Is this a known issue? Or limitation of the free offering?

```
sudo docker login jfrog.io/acme 
Username: admin 
Password: 
Error response from daemon: Get https://jfrog.io/v2/: x509: certificate is valid for jfrog.com, *.jfrog.com, not jfrog.io
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you should be using `my-account.jfrog.io` and not `my-account.jfrog.com`.
The docker login command which you are running is wrong. It is missing your account name (as a sub domain), so instead of calling `jfrog.io` you should be calling `my-account.jfrog.io` (for example daniel.jfrog.io)

The reason for getting the certificate error is that when trying to perform docker login directly to jfrog.io (without the subdomain) docker is trying to access an invalid URL - jfrog.io/v2. As a result it is being redirected to an 403 error page on jfrog.com which does not match the jfrog.io certificate.

To test your docker repository please follow the following steps:

Login to your repository with docker login command. Make sure to use your account name instead of `my-account`. Please notice that you do not need the repository name for the login command.

```
docker login my-account.jfrog.io
```

Pull the hello-world image from the Dockerhub

```
docker pull hello-world
```

Tag the hello-world image so it can be pushed to your repository (assuming it is a [local repository](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Local+Repositories) and you have the [permissions](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Permissions) to push an image). Make sure to use your account name and repo name

```
docker tag hello-world my-account.jfrog.io/my-repo/hello-world
```

Push the tagged image to your repository

```
docker push my-account.jfrog.io/my-repo/hello-world
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply ..  But this wasn't the question! I left the original command line presented in the JFrrog UI to login to show the certificate issue.

The login has to contain the sub-domain as I figured out once I marked the registry as unsafe and got past the certificate error. 

Using the right sub domain does not solve the certificate error. 

The certificate is only valid for the .com domain not the .io domain.

Daniel

Comment: @DanielNashed the login command you show in your answer does not include the sub domain. If you go to your JFrog account using a web browser you can see that the certificate which is being used is for jfrog.io and has no issues. What happens when you try do docker login jfrog.io (without the subdomain) is that docker is being redirected to an error page on jfrog.com which cause the certificate error.
If the issue is not with the docker login or if the command you shared in the question is not correct, please update the question to be more clear about the exact issue you are currently having

Comment: @DanielNashed are you getting the certificate error when running other commands like pull/push? if so please share more details

Comment: Thanks! I think I know what happened..  In one of the instructions somewhere online the account was missing in the example. I did not revert the untrusted certificate check.  company.jfrog.io goes to a different host than jfrog.io. I wrongly assumed they are the same.  I was focused on the certificate not the hostname.  I removed the untrusted option in the Docker deamon and it still works.   Thanks! that was the solution.